# how to insert snapshots from rgl window into ordinary R plot

Tags: r, plot, snapshot, rgl, insets

I am using R package `rgl` to create interactive plots and then its function `rgl.snapshot` to export images from them. I am wondering, however, if there is a way how to insert snapshots from the interactive `rgl` plot directly into insets of an ordinary R plot.
Does anybody have experience with such task?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(png)
library(rgl)

example(surface3d)
rgl.snapshot("plot.png")

plot(0:10, 10:0)
img <- readPNG("plot.png")
rasterImage(as.raster(img), 4, 2, 8, 6)
```